# How to count the number of the right classification for our prediction array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

If I want to classify a data set labeled `+1` or `-1`

```
y_te=[-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, +1, -1, -1];
```

I get an output corresponding to `y_te`

```
pred_array=[ -1.0627, 0.4768 , -1.0883, 0.3033, -1.3152, 0.3569, -0.1990, 0.347];
```

The principle of prediction is:
If this element is positive then label `+1`, otherwise label `-1`. For the first element in our prediction `-1.0627` label `-1` which is the right classification in `y_te`. But the last one `0.347` is labeled `+1` in our prediction, which is the wrong classification. Totally, there are 7 right classifications (4 times `-1`, 3 times `+1`) and 1 wrong classification.

How to count the number of the right classification for our prediction array?

In other words, given two arrays. I want to count the number of the same sign `+1` or `-1` in these two matching arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total number of right predictions is

```
right = sum(sign(y_te)==sign(pred_array));
```

The number of right positive predictions is

```
right_pos = sum(y_te>0 & pred_array>0);
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks. Can we get the exact number of right classification for +1? And the number of +1 that is wrong classified to -1?

Comment: @Lucas Edited. But why wasn't that in the original question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following algorithm:

```
% transform the array into the binary array (such as an indicator function)
I_y_te = y_te > 0; 

% transform the array into the binary array (such as an indicator function)
I_pred = pred_array > 0; 

% compare when two elements of there binary arrays are equal
right = I_pred - I_y_te; 

% find the number of equalities in terms of the number of zeros
num_of_right_classification = nnz(~right);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can we get the exact number of right classification for +1? And the number of +1 that is wrong classified to -1?

Comment: @Lucas my pleasure. Yes, you can. As `I_pred` is `-1` and `I_y_te` is `+1`, you need to find all `-1` in the `right`.